# Adobe CQ. Restrict access to site with login/password popup window

Tags: authentication, passwords, adobe, aem, restrict

I've faced with a problem. I wanna to show user the popup window when he enters my site. I mean, only specific group of users are able to visit it. How can i do it with CQ? I have investigated alot, but still nothing works. I was thinking to do it with the help of Day CQ HTTP Header Authentication Handler. I added specific path in it's config but nothing changed.  Now I am trying to write my own login service. Can you help with ideas? Maybe there is something I have missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a [Closed User Group](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/security/cug.html) on the publish instance.
Second, you need to determine if you need a popup instead of initial page load, or load a default page that runs JavaScript to create the popup if the user doesn't have an active session.